# Free CDN Hosting for Javascripts to be used in a site in a vpn

Tags: cdn

Are there free CDN hosting, I want to upload my custom javascript through a CDN hosting to increase the speed of my site

Answer (score 0):

Being a static file you could use [github.com](https://github.com/) it already provides a CDN or in any case, you could complement it with https://rawgit.com/.

If you have your own servers you could use [Cloudflare](https://www.cloudflare.com/)

Comment: rowgit will stop working in October 2019 and it will not host new files anymore only those that was created after September 2018. "GitHub repositories that served content through RawGit within the last month will continue to be served until at least October of 2019" and post was written in October 8. https://rawgit.com/